# Are there any compatiblity issues with using CJS and ESM modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

I have read several *"ESM in NodeJS"* articles as of late, consequently; I decided to convert a CJS module I had into an ES-Module (2020). Before I even began writing code, I noticed something that was overwhelming — though it wasn't completely unexpected — my page was one big red squiggly *error*. I found it easier to just rewrite the whole module, even though it took me a couple days.

So now I am at a point where I can't help but to wonder if ESM is necessary. To put it more simply: Am I going to run into comparability issues down the road if I don't start using ESM modules today, or can I continue to use CJS?

Comment: I had a difficult time wording this question. I am trying to determine if witting the module I started a few days ago, as an ES-Module is worth it. There are a couple small, but notable things I had to give up. I do like the Import export statements, but I cant help to feel that there are probably more important reasons to develop a module as either a Common JavaScript Module, or as a ES Module, Compatibility and support were my biggest concerns.

Comment: All new projects should be written as ESM modules as that is the present and the future of the language and nodejs.  It's highly, highly unlikely that CJS modules will lose support for a very long time because a huge portion of the nodejs eco-system is still CJS modules and I rather doubt that the nodejs leadership wants to create the kind of situation Python did with 2.0 => 3.0 which was not pleasant in the developer community.  Plus, the dual compatibility in nodejs is already there and not really harming anything right now.

Comment: There are some CJS conveniences like `__dirname` that are not as convenient in EJS.  And, EJS requires static export declarations (they can't be computed like they can be in CJS) which is good news for bundlers, but rules out some situations where you might to do dynamic exports.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, that's one of the big reasons I considered not switching. I know there is a workaround for __dirname, but I really like having __dirname as is, with no added logic, or path formatting. Its a small thing, but its extremely fundamental. At this point, I kind of feel like if the CJS modules arn't in the plans to be phased out, and they will work harmoniously with everything, I might as well stick with them. I mean why change?

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh okay, I read your comments backwards. So moving forth the plan is to make ESM the Standard?

Comment: ESM ***is*** the module standard in Javascript.  Nodejs is moving to fully support that standard.  New code should be written as ESM modules.  I would expect some new features in the future to only be available in ESM modules as that's where the development and innovation is happening.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, I figured it was going to be something like that, or actually I thought that it would be exactly that but I couldn't find anything when I googled plans for ESM or CJS. Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Comment: In case you didn't realize, CJS is node-specific, not a Javascript standard.  The developers behind nodejs took ideas from existing 3rd party module systems, molded them to fit into the needs of nodejs and built them into the first version of nodejs.  They are not a Javascript standard.  ESM are now part of the Javascript standard and nodejs has been adopting that new standard and filling in a few bits where they needed more than the standard offers (for things like `__dirname`).

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, I think I can dig it. So like, in-other-words: The module type **`Common-JS`** is not a `ECMAS` defined module type, and therefore, it is not standard `JavaScript`, where as;  **`ES-Modules`**  are defined by `ECMA-Scripts`, therefore **`ES-Modules`** are standard `JavaScript`. That is why node is choosing to make the switch, and that is why you suggest that, hence forth, developers write the contemporary 'ESM' modules, over the original old'skool `CJS` modules.

Comment: Yep, that's the reasoning I'm proposing.  I guess I'll write that into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All new projects should be written as ESM modules as that is the present and the future of the Javascript language and nodejs. It's highly, highly unlikely that CJS modules will lose support for a very long time because a huge portion of the nodejs eco-system is still CJS modules and I rather doubt that the nodejs leadership wants to create the kind of situation Python did with 2.0 => 3.0 which was not pleasant in the developer community. Plus, the dual compatibility in nodejs is already there and not really harming anything right now.

There are some CJS conveniences like `__dirname` that are not as convenient in EJS. And, EJS requires static export declarations (they can't be computed like they can be in CJS) which is good news for bundlers, but rules out some situations where you might to do dynamic exports.

ESM **is** the module standard in Javascript. Nodejs is moving to fully support that standard. New code should be written as ESM modules. I would expect some new features in the future to only be available in ESM modules as that's where the development and innovation is happening.

CJS is node-specific, not a Javascript standard. The developers behind nodejs took ideas from existing 3rd party module systems, molded them to fit into the needs of nodejs and built them into the first version of nodejs. They are not a Javascript standard. ESM are now part of the Javascript standard and nodejs has been adopting that new standard and filling in a few bits where they needed more than the standard offers.

Comment: I appreciate you answering it, as it allows me to mark the question as answered —  even more-so,  I appreciate you taking the time to converse with me, as a result, I have a much better understanding of what the ESM and CJS modules are.

Comment: Considering when this answer was posted and the current state of ESM in Node land. There are massive problems with ESM as it stands. ESM+TS+JEST is problematic. Mocks are nearly impossible. This is just the tip of the iceberg.